# Adding an order for a customer selected from a list view in Access

Tags: database, listview, ms-access, vba

I followed this great guide to help me add a search feature to my Access database:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-populate-an-access-list-control-with-the-results-of-a-dynamic-search/108

At the end it says:

"If you’re building a quote or order, use the list control’s Click or Double Click event to copy record(s) to a temporary table. It’s easy to implement using a fixed query for each search task."

I have managed to display all search results in a list box and **I would like to be able to click on a customer to highlight them, and then press a button to add an order to the selected customer.** I've been thinking how I could do it and I really can't get my head around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The link seems to demonstrate searching for a number of items to be added to a list. You would seem to be searching for items to which a list is to be added. I am fairly sure you should not be doing it this way. A simple subform would allow you to add orders to customers with very little or no code. The wizards will allow you to create a combobox to navigate by customer name through your form.

Comment: I have implemented the method that the link describes to see if a customer exists in the database. If they do (from searching) I want to click on them and add an order for the selected customer. I'm not sure if you quite know what I'm trying to do, so hopefully this makes it a bit clearer. Surely by somehow clicking on the row, I can grab the ID of the customer and 'pass' it to another form to add an order? I am quite new to this, so if I'm being unrealistic in my approach, please do say so.

Comment: I think you have made your life a lot more difficult than it needs to be. There are any number of ways to use an ID to add an order to a table.

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain/link me to an explanation of how this can be achieved?

Comment: No, not really. You have set out on a path I do not wish to study, so I do not know where your id is coming from or where it is going to, which is why I have commented, rather than answered. A form that allows the user to add the other information needed for an order may suit. Customer number is not enough for a suitable order record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you build your database. My guess is that one easy way would be:

- Create a table with customers;
- Create an "Order" table with orders where you link the customers through a foreign key
- You load the customers in a listbox. While making the name visible, it is actually the ID that you retrieve when clicking the listbox. You can configure this via the wizard in the design view of a table. You can make other forms appear by events on the listbox (eg. on click).
- If you managed to retrieve the ID of the customer, and you have the data related to the order (data that can easily be extracted from form objects and loaded into variables ) what you need is an insert statement and insert the values in the "Order" tabel (including the customer ID, which is linked through the foreign key).
- This way all order records are linked to the customer and can be queried later.

Due to my limited knowledge on your other requests, I cannot help you any further on the rest of your database design. 
I hope that my reply could help you and that I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Regarding point 3, I did not use the wizard to create the list, I am using a search field to produce a query, and populating the listview from that. Surely if there is a way to do it in the wizard, there is a way to do it with code?

Comment: Okay, I've come to the conclusion that it is the 'Bound Column' property. How do I then use this in the following form to add an order for that customer?

Comment: Why not putting them in one form? First select customer, then select order and click confirm or something?

Comment: What I was thinking of doing is:

- Clicking a row, which will then set the selected row to the ID
- Opening the new form and setting the ID to the one selected
- Add the details of the order

This however isnt working as it won't let me manually enter the customer ID, only choose the customer name from a combo box. Is there a way I can click on the row, then open my tbl_AddOrder form and add details about that order for the selected customer?

Comment: Sorted it, I added a new field which would let me select the record by typing in the ID. Thanks.

Comment: Ok ;-) I'm sorry, I was off for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can access info from a listbox via:

```
List.Value
```

Or if it is not the first column then:

```
List.Column(0,0)
```

0 being the column and row references.

You may also consider using a listview over a listbox and then you can access the relevant parts of a listview control with the following code:

```
ListView.SelectedItem
```

Or if it is not the first column then:

```
ListView.SelectedItem.SubItems(3)
```

3 being the column reference