# VBA ListView control - retrieve columns from selected item

Tags: vba, listview, ms-access

I have a ListView object within my Microsoft Access database that is set to **Report View**.  When a user selects a row from this list, I want to be able to open a secondary form and populate based on the selected values.  I am running into trouble with the proper syntax for capturing the column values I need.  I have searched high and low looking for information on this, however I have not been able to find anything that fits my particular criteria.

Here is the code in question:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemClick(ByVal Item As Object)

  Dim FormID, FilingID, RowIndex As Integer
  Dim FilingName As String

  RowIndex = Item.Index

  FormID = Item.SubItems(0)
  FilingID = Item.SubItems(1)
  FilingName = Item.SubItems(2)

  If MsgBox("Do you want to open up filing " & FilingName & "?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
     DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFiling", acNormal, , , , , "FormID=" & FormID & ";FilingID=" & FilingID
  End If

End Sub
```

This code keeps throwing an exception on the line FormID = Item.SubItems(0) stating that it is an invalid property value.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here, or have a workaround that accomplishes what I am trying to do?

Comment: What is Item? The control name is ListView1. Consider `ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(0)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207439/adding-an-order-for-a-customer-selected-from-a-list-view-in-access

Comment: Or `ListView1.Items[1].SubItems[1].Text` https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aff668e2-8d2a-4a89-b26f-9dbf430de97f/get-value-of-listview-item-and-subitems?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I tried both of these alternatives, the first option (ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(0) throws "Invalid property value"; the second option throws "object doesnt support this property or method"

Comment: I changed the event from ItemClick to Click, and used ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text to extract the column value.

Answer (score 0):

In your line `FormID = Item.SubItems(0)` where you declared FormID as a variant, you are assigning an object to it, so VBA expects `SET FormID = Item.SubItems(0)`.

However what you want is probably `FormID = CInt(Item.SubItems(0).Text)`

Comment: both of these statements throw invalid property value exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the event from ItemClick to Click, and used ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text to extract the column value.

Thanks everyone for your comments.